# SSR altern symbol why

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

Why in the SS relay the connection line 1 and 2 appear a altern symbol, can I use to connect a DC line ?

The symbol above 24~380VAC is a capacitor ?

[image]

Comment: Did you read the datasheet?

Comment: I read another datasheet for SSR 3P, always says three phase motor in schemtics of wiring. I dont know if I can connect a DC

Comment: Why did you read a datasheet for SSR 3P? It something else than your question shows... Or did you post some random image and left the relevant information (being: "you want to use a SSR 3P") out of your question?

Answer (score 2):

The '~' (tilde) symbol tells you that it is for AC.  Internally it is using a triac and these are only suitable for AC switching.

The `-| |-` symbol represents a normally open contact and is common on North American electrical schematics.

The 24-380VAC text indicates that it is rated for switching voltages in that range (which excludes DC).

---

**Counterfeit Fotek SSRs**

It appears that you are considering Fotek SSRs. Read this first: 
[UL warns of solid state relay with counterfeit UL Recognition Mark (Release 13PN-52)](http://www.ul.com/newsroom/publicnotices/ul-warns-of-solid-state-relay-with-counterfeit-ul-recognition-mark-release-13pn-52/).

See also Big Clive's [Teardown of an eBay 25A Solid State Relay (SSR)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxEhxjvifyY&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: They have a DC variant as well...

Comment: I know, but that wasn't the question. d:^)

Comment: the question is...Can I use a SSR 3P to switch three beacon 24 vdc :/

Comment: No, that is not the question. Read your question again. There is no mention of SSR 3P and there is no mention of 24 V DC beacons. Your question was, "Can I use this SSR to switch DC"? The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

From the datasheet (I leave you the effort to find the datasheet):

[image]